# Compile timeout

Tags: pgfplots

When I use my code, always say that-compile timeout-www.overleaf.com/
I am check two times my code and dont finde any mistake

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepackage{caption} % <----
    \captionsetup{font = small} % <----

\usepackage[active,floats,tightpage]{preview}% <---
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

    \begin{document}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{figure} % <---
    \centering % <---
\begin{tikzpicture}
%%%% f1
    \begin{axis}[scale only axis,
        xlabel=Time,
        xmin=0, xmax=168,
        ylabel={log(Cfu/cm$^{2}$)},
        axis y line*=left,
        ymin=0, ymax=10,
        legend style={at={(0.48,-0.15)},  % <---
                      anchor=north east}] % <---
    \addplot [black, fill=white, mark=square*]
        table[row sep=crcr]{
            0 7.005\\
2 7\\
4 7.035\\
6 7.005\\
8 7.015\\
10 7.025\\
12 6.98\\
14 6.985\\
16 6.94\\
18 6.89\\
20 6.81\\
22 6.63\\
24 6.46\\
48 5.945\\
72 6.445\\
168 6.845\\};
             \addplot [black, fill=white, mark=*]
        table[row sep=crcr]{
            0 7\\
2 7.02\\
4 7.03\\
6 7.01\\
8 7.025\\
10 7.03\\
12 6.98\\
14 6.92\\
16 6.895\\
18 6.78\\
20 6.62\\
22 6.415\\
24 6.205\\
48 6.37\\
72 6.49\\
168 6.865\\};
            \addplot [black, fill=white, mark=diamond*]
        table[row sep=crcr]{
           0 7.01\\
2 7.02\\
4 7.045\\
6 7.01\\
8 7.03\\
10 7.025\\
12 6.98\\
14 6.955\\
16 6.905\\
18 6.825\\
20 6.725\\
22 6.575\\
24 6.43\\
48 6.27\\
72 6.345\\
168 6.975\\};
            \addlegendentry{plot 3} % <---
            \addplot [black, fill=white, mark=triangle*]
        table[row sep=crcr]{
          0 7.005\\
2 7.02\\
4 7.03\\
6 7.02\\
8 7.01\\
10 7.02\\
12 6.99\\
14 6.975\\
16 6.93\\
18 6.845\\
20 6.715\\
22 6.53\\
24 6.315};
48 6.32\\
72 6.405\\
168 6.785\\};
    \label{plot_one}
    \addlegendentry{plot 4}
    \end{axis}
%%%% f2
    \begin{axis}[scale only axis,
        hide x axis,
        xmin=0, xmax=168,
        ylabel={Relative Expression},
        axis y line*=right,
        ymin=0, ymax=6,   
        legend style={at={(0.52,-0.15)}, % <---
                      anchor=north west}]% <---
]
%    \addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=plot_one}
    \addplot [black, mark=square*]
        table[row sep=crcr]{
           0 0.051\\
2 0.0175\\
4 0.0945\\
6 0.122\\
8 0.135\\
10 0.14\\
12 0.1745\\
14 0.1855\\
16 0.29\\
18 0.423\\
20 0.574\\
22 0.8165\\
24 1.061\\
48 1.985\\
72 2.0285\\
168 1.9215\\};

             \addplot [black, mark=*]
        table[row sep=crcr]{
            0 1.6\\
0 0.052\\
2 0.0165\\
4 0.1495\\
6 0.1805\\
8 0.1835\\
10 0.1855\\
12 0.2005\\
14 0.3795\\
16 0.5425\\
18 0.8065\\
20 1.046\\
22 1.2005\\
24 1.483\\
48 2.369\\
72 2.0315\\
168 2.3025\\};


            \addplot [black, mark=diamond*]
        table[row sep=crcr]{
            0 0.053\\
2 0.0485\\
4 0.1365\\
6 0.164\\
8 0.1595\\
10 0.1725\\
12 0.1935\\
14 0.2315\\
16 0.3345\\
18 0.473\\
20 0.6015\\
22 0.8185\\
24 1.0415\\
48 2.082\\
72 1.919\\
168 1.711\\};
    \addlegendentry{plot 3} % <---
            \addplot [black, mark=triangle*]
        table[row sep=crcr]{
0 0.0525\\
2 0.0325\\
4 0.0285\\
6 0.108\\
8 0.1255\\
10 0.1475\\
12 0.1405\\
14 0.2495\\
16 0.3955\\
18 0.529\\
20 0.7175\\
22 0.9715\\
24 1.2455\\
48 1.94\\
72 1.696\\
168 1.942\\};
    \label{plot_four}
    \addlegendentry{plot 4} % <---
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

    \caption{Growth of different types foodborne pathogens.} % <---
    \end{figure} % <---
\end{document}
```

Comment: Line `24 6.315};` is wrong: should be ``24 6.315\\``. This sort of thing can be found by commenting out parts of the document systematically (which is what I did).

Comment: Also, How can I To connect legends name for example write: mark black and mark white plot 3

Comment: I've no real idea what you mean, but more importantly you've been asked repeatedly to make you questions self-contained and clear. I don't see you need all of the above code to make an example asking about legends.

Comment: Dear Joseph, I agree with you, that I bad explain my problem in english. Because I edit question add picture , what I want. Thank you

Comment: The image didn't make sense in relation to _this question_ so I rolled back the last edit.

Comment: Dear David Hpw can I prepare legend same as picture wich you delete?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This loops forever

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepackage{caption} % <----
    \captionsetup{font = small} % <----

\usepackage[active,floats,tightpage]{preview}% <---
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

    \begin{document}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{figure} % <---
    \centering % <---
\begin{tikzpicture}
%%%% f1
    \begin{axis}[scale only axis,
        xlabel=Time,
        xmin=0, xmax=168,
        ylabel={log(Cfu/cm$^{2}$)},
        axis y line*=left,
        ymin=0, ymax=10,
        legend style={at={(0.48,-0.15)},  % <---
                      anchor=north east}] % <---
    \addplot [black, fill=white, mark=square*]
        table[row sep=crcr]{
            0 7.005\\
2 7\\
4 7.035\\
6 7.005\\
8 7.015\\
10 7.025\\
12 6.98\\
14 6.985\\
16 6.94\\
18 6.89\\
20 6.81\\
22 6.63\\
24 6.46\\
48 5.945\\
72 6.445\\
168 6.845\\};

\addplot [black, fill=white, mark=*]
        table[row sep=crcr]{
            0 7\\
2 7.02\\
4 7.03\\
6 7.01\\
8 7.025\\
10 7.03\\
12 6.98\\
14 6.92\\
16 6.895\\
18 6.78\\
20 6.62\\
22 6.415\\
24 6.205\\
48 6.37\\
72 6.49\\
168 6.865\\};


\addplot [black, fill=white, mark=diamond*]
        table[row sep=crcr]{
           0 7.01\\
2 7.02\\
4 7.045\\
6 7.01\\
8 7.03\\
10 7.025\\
12 6.98\\
14 6.955\\
16 6.905\\
18 6.825\\
20 6.725\\
22 6.575\\
24 6.43\\
48 6.27\\
72 6.345\\
168 6.975\\};


\addlegendentry{plot 3} % <---
            \addplot [black, fill=white, mark=triangle*]
        table[row sep=crcr]{
          0 7.005\\
2 7.02\\
4 7.03\\
6 7.02\\
8 7.01\\
10 7.02\\
12 6.99\\
14 6.975\\
16 6.93\\
18 6.845\\
20 6.715\\
22 6.53\\
24 6.315};
48 6.32\\
72 6.405\\
168 6.785\\};
    \label{plot_one}
    \addlegendentry{plot 4}
    \end{axis}
%%%% f2


\end{tikzpicture}

    \caption{Growth of different types foodborne pathogens.} % <---
    \end{figure} % <---
\end{document}
```

but if you change

the last part

```
24 6.315};
48 6.32\\
72 6.405\\
168 6.785\\};
```

to

```
24 6.315\\};
```

then it runs.